# Laravel Mailtrap SMTP Crack

Tags: php, security, email, smtp, laravel

I have an older Laravel 5.7 project handed to me. Laravel's current version is 8. I don't know if these details are relevant to my problem, but I'm adding them anyway. I have a test server running off an IP address (no domain) for the clients to see the progress as I push new features to GitHub. This GitHub project is set as private and the server is properly configured to only show the public folder. The private repo also does not have a hard coded `.env` file, so even if someone was to get into my GitHub, he would not be able to get any real information from the `.env` file, as it is blank and is configured directly on the server.

To my main issue. I am using Mailtrap for testing purposes and I keep getting unauthorized mail like this:
[image: Screenshot Of Email]

I have tried deleting my Mailtrap mailbox and recreating it to get new credentials, but some random script kiddie always happens to crack the SMTP server. At the moment, since my SMTP is connected to Mailtrap, this is harmless. But when I get the real website online, I'm worried about how these crackers are doing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered instead that someone has actually cracked the Laravel project and is sending spam through it?

Comment: I'm new to Laravel, so I'm not sure what "cracked the Laravel project" means. Could you give a bit more detail? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cracked means: Found a security hole in it and exploited it.

Comment: Yes, I know. I thought you meant something specifically about encryption when you said cracked. Miscommunication I guess.

Comment: You probably should get someone else you trust to review the application code.

Comment: Laravel 5.7 hasn't had security fixes in over a year, and your application probably hasn't for much longer than that. So yes, update the framework and get someone to look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

The main reasons this can happen are:

- Your production website is APP_DEBUG=true

Change the setting in your .env to false for debug mode, otherwise your app details are visible if anyone can get your site to display an error page.

- Your website is configured incorrectly and .env is visible

Try visiting yourwebsite.com/.env or your.ip.add.ress/.env and see if you can view your .env files

- You have installed Laravel into a sub-directory, meaning your site files are visible